How to remove these braces around this lamda expression?
Sonarlint I use with IntelliJ sends me a warning S1602 "Remove useless curly braces around statement" on this statement :
communes.foreachPartition(
   partition -> {
      partition.forEachRemaining(commune -> this.validator.validerRowCommune(historique, commune));
   }
);

(where:
communes is an org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset<Row>
partition is an Iterator<Row>
and commune is a Row)
In this next function:
public Dataset<Row> rowCommunes(OptionsCreationLecture optionsCreationLecture, HistoriqueExecution historique, int anneeCOG, boolean inclureCommunesDelegueesAssociees, Verification... verifications) {
   OptionsCreationLecture options = optionsCreationLecture != null ? optionsCreationLecture : optionsCreationLecture();

   if (historique != null) {
      historique.addReglesValidation(this.session, this.validator);
   }

   Supplier<Dataset<Row>> worker = () -> {
      super.setStageDescription(this.messageSource, "row.cog.libelle.long", "row.cog.libelle.court", anneeCOG, inclureCommunesDelegueesAssociees);
      LOGGER.info(this.messageSource.getMessage("row.cog.libelle.long", new Object[] {anneeCOG, inclureCommunesDelegueesAssociees}, Locale.getDefault()));

      // Lier les codes communes et codes communes parents à leurs siren
      Dataset<Row> c = this.cogCsvLoader.loadOpenData(anneeCOG, inclureCommunesDelegueesAssociees);
      Dataset<Row> s = this.datasetSirenCommunaux.rowSirenCommunes(options, new SirenCommunesTriDepartementCommuneSiren(), anneeCOG);
      Dataset<Row> communes = lierCommunesEtSiren(c,s).union(lierCommunesParentesEtSiren(c,s));

      communes = communes.dropDuplicates("codeCommune", "typeCommune", "nomCommune");

      communes = populationEtStrateCommunale(communes);
      communes = liercontoursCommunes(communes, anneeCOG, verifications);

      // Associer à chaque commune son code intercommunalité, si elle en a un (les communes-communautés peuvent ne pas en avoir).
      Dataset<Row> perimetres = this.datasetPerimetres.rowPerimetres(this.session, anneeCOG, EPCIPerimetreDataset.TriPerimetresEPCI.CODE_COMMUNE_MEMBRE).selectExpr("sirenCommuneMembre", "sirenGroupement as codeEPCI", "nomGroupement as nomEPCI");
      Column conditionJoinPerimetres = communes.col("sirenCommune").equalTo(perimetres.col("sirenCommuneMembre"));

      verificateur().verifications("jonction communes et périmètres", communes, null, perimetres, conditionJoinPerimetres, verifications, Verification.SHOW_REJETS, Verification.COMPTAGES_ET_STATISTIQUES);
      communes = communes.join(perimetres, conditionJoinPerimetres, "left");

      // Y associer les départements.
      communes = this.datasetDepartements.withDepartement("codeDepartementRetabli", communes, "codeDepartement", null, true, anneeCOG)
         .drop("codeRegionDepartement")
         .drop("codeDepartementRetabli");

      communes.foreachPartition(
         partition -> {
            partition.forEachRemaining(commune -> this.validator.validerRowCommune(historique, commune));
         }
      );

      return communes;
   };

   return constitutionStandard(options, worker,
      new CacheParqueteur<>(options, this.session,
         "cog-communes", "FILTRE-annee_{0,number,#0}_COMD-COMA_{1}",
         new CogTriDepartementCommune(), anneeCOG, inclureCommunesDelegueesAssociees));
}

I made many tries, but didn't found the way to remove these braces.
For example, it's not:
communes.foreachPartition(
   partition -> partition.forEachRemaining(commune -> this.validator.validerRowCommune(historique, commune));
);



it looks like you have an additional semicolon in your last snippet at the end of line 2. Is that the issue?

who or what gave you this warning?

@Stultuske Sonarlint used inside IntelliJ

IntelliJ should also provide an automatic reformatting if you use alt + enter (windows/linux) or opt + enter (mac) on the code piece with the squiggly line and the warning.

@ODDminus1 In this case it doesn't. The context menu coming with Alt-Enter displays "shows rule description" or "disable the rule". No all rules are accompanied with a reformatting, alas.

regarding my first comment, did you attempt to remove the semicolon in your last code snippet?

"For example, it's not: ..." without any error message?!

I added a capture what I saw when I removed the braces. Three errors marks.

still no "error message"  :-(  ||| probably being output in some different view and also displayed if hovering the mouse over the marked words in the IDE, does not work for posted image (assuming an IDE is doing that)

SonarLint is suggesting that you remove the curly-braces from a one-line lambda expression - which is good practice!
What you showed is very close to fixing it.
Here's an example of a lambda with a body:
() -> {
    example();
}

Here's an example of a lambda without a body (curly-braces):
() -> example()

What you will notice, is that lambda-expressions without bodies does not end with semi-colons (;).
Solution
So, the answer to your question is, change the code to this:
communes.foreachPartition(
   partition -> partition.forEachRemaining(commune -> this.validator.validerRowCommune(historique, commune))
);


Marc Le Bihan (OP) edit:
You have the solution. I was tricked by three errors marks on my expression when I removed the braces, like I've shown in my last question edit.
The final working lambda requires a (ForeachPartitionFunction<Row>) cast that you can't figure (due to the Spark classes hierarchy). It's:
communes.foreachPartition((ForeachPartitionFunction<Row>)partition ->
   partition.forEachRemaining(commune -> this.validator.validerRowCommune(historique, commune))
);

Thanks again!

Your "example of a lambda with a body" does not end with a semicolon either. Its body contains a semicolon, but that semicolon is not the end of the expression. I'm a little bit out-of-practice these days, but I'm pretty sure that it's not just lambda expressions. I don't believe that there is any expression in Java that ends with a semicolon. If it ends with a semicolon, then it must be a statement or a declaration of some kind.

D'Oh! Stupid me. Of course, the expressions that control a classic for loop are separated by semicolons.

You can update your code from
communes.foreachPartition(
   partition -> {
      partition.forEachRemaining(commune -> this.validator.validerRowCommune(historique, commune));
   }
);

to
communes.foreachPartition(
   partition ->
      partition.forEachRemaining(commune -> this.validator.validerRowCommune(historique, commune))
);

You can read more about it here. https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-lambda-expressions-tips
